# How to take multiple rows and convert some of them into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have the following data set:

```
QuestionID  RowID       ColID       MenuID  SourceRowID  SourceColumnID  SourceVariationID  ResponseCount  
----------  ----------  ----------  ------  -----------  --------------  -----------------  -------------  
316923119   3029903189  3029903193  0       3029903177   3029903181      0                  773            
316923119   3029903189  3029903193  0       3029903177   3029903182      0                  788            
316923119   3029903189  3029903193  0       3029903177   3029903183      0                  778            
316923119   3029903189  3029903193  0       3029903177   3029903184      0                  803            
316923119   3029903189  3029903194  0       3029903177   3029903181      0                  766            
316923119   3029903189  3029903194  0       3029903177   3029903182      0                  799            
316923119   3029903189  3029903194  0       3029903177   3029903183      0                  782
316923119   3029903189  3029903194  0       3029903177   3029903184      0                  773
```

I want to convert it to this dataset:

```
QuestionID  RowID       ColumnID    MenuID  3029903181  3029903182  3029903183  3029903184  ResponseCount  
----------  ----------  ----------  ------  -------     -------     -------      -------    -------------         
316923119   3029903189  3029903193   0        773        788          778         803          3142          
316923119   3029903189  3029903194   0        766        799          782         773          3120
```

These are represented as this in Python:

```
 [
  {
    'QuestionID': 316923119, 
    'RowID': 3029903189, 
    'ColID': 3029903193, 
    'SourceColumnID': 3029903181,
    'ResponseCount': 773
  },
  {
    'QuestionID': 316923119, 
    'RowID': 3029903189, 
    'ColID': 3029903193, 
    'SourceColumnID': 3029903182,
    'ResponseCount': 788
  },
  {
    'QuestionID': 316923119, 
    'RowID': 3029903189, 
    'ColID': 3029903193, 
    'SourceColumnID': 3029903183,
    'ResponseCount': 778
  },
  {
    'QuestionID': 316923119, 
    'RowID': 3029903189, 
    'ColID': 3029903193, 
    'SourceColumnID': 3029903184,
    'ResponseCount': 803
  },
  {
    'QuestionID': 316923119, 
    'RowID': 3029903189, 
    'ColID': 3029903194, 
    'SourceColumnID': 3029903181,
    'ResponseCount': 766
  },
  {
    'QuestionID': 316923119, 
    'RowID': 3029903189, 
    'ColID': 3029903194, 
    'SourceColumnID': 3029903182,
    'ResponseCount': 799
  },
  {
    'QuestionID': 316923119, 
    'RowID': 3029903189, 
    'ColID': 3029903194, 
    'SourceColumnID': 3029903183,
    'ResponseCount': 782
  },
  {
    'QuestionID': 316923119, 
    'RowID': 3029903189, 
    'ColID': 3029903194, 
    'SourceColumnID': 3029903184,
    'ResponseCount': 773
  },
]
```

and I want to get:

```
[
  {
    'QuestionID': 316923119, 
    'RowID': 3029903189, 
    'ColID': 3029903193, 
    '3029903181': 773,
    '3029903182': 788,
    '3029903183': 778,
    '3029903184': 803,
    'ResponseCount': 3142
  },
  {
    'QuestionID': 316923119, 
    'RowID': 3029903189, 
    'ColID': 3029903194, 
    '3029903181': 766,
    '3029903182': 799,
    '3029903183': 782,
    '3029903184': 773,
    'ResponseCount': 3120
  },
]
```

The big changes here is combining the rows SourceColumnID into Columns grouped by the same QuestionID, RowID, and ColID and then totally them all together into a new column ResponseCount.

I would prefer loading this data into pandas and transforming it with a DataFrame but any suggestion is welcome.

## EDIT

The Answer from TomAugspurger below almost works:

```
In [90]: df
Out[90]: 
        ColID  QuestionID  ResponseCount       RowID  SourceColumnID
0  3029903193   316923119            773  3029903189      3029903181
1  3029903193   316923119            788  3029903189      3029903182
2  3029903193   316923119            778  3029903189      3029903183
3  3029903193   316923119            803  3029903189      3029903184
4  3029903194   316923119            766  3029903189      3029903181
5  3029903194   316923119            799  3029903189      3029903182
6  3029903194   316923119            782  3029903189      3029903183
7  3029903194   316923119            773  3029903189      3029903184

[8 rows x 5 columns]

In [91]: counts = df.pivot_table(values='ResponseCount', rows=['ColID', 'QuestionID', 'RowID'], cols='SourceColumnID', aggfunc='sum')

In [92]: counts['ResponseCount'] = counts.sum(1)

In [93]: counts
Out[93]: 
SourceColumnID                    3029903181  3029903182  3029903183  3029903184  ResponseCount
ColID      QuestionID RowID                                                                    
3029903193 316923119  3029903189         773         788         778         803           3142
3029903194 316923119  3029903189         766         799         782         773           3120

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

but this doesn't allow me to access the data in the way I need, I should be able to grab counts and access on the new columns to get their counts:

```
counts[0][3029903181]
```

should return 773

Found this to work:

```
int(counts.iloc[0][3029903181])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot table should do the trick.

```
In [54]: counts = df.pivot_table(values='ResponseCount',
                                 rows=['ColID', 'QuestionID', 'RowID'],
                                 cols='SourceColumnID', aggfunc='sum')

In [55]: counts
Out[55]: 
SourceColumnID                    3029903181  3029903182  3029903183  \
ColID      QuestionID RowID                                            
3029903193 316923119  3029903189         773         788         778   
3029903194 316923119  3029903189         766         799         782   

SourceColumnID                    3029903184  
ColID      QuestionID RowID                   
3029903193 316923119  3029903189         803  
3029903194 316923119  3029903189         773  

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

To get the `ResponseCount` column it looks like you're summing across the columns:

```
In [57]: counts['ResponseCount'] = counts.sum(1)

In [58]: counts
Out[58]: 
SourceColumnID                    3029903181  3029903182  3029903183  \
ColID      QuestionID RowID                                            
3029903193 316923119  3029903189         773         788         778   
3029903194 316923119  3029903189         766         799         782   

SourceColumnID                    3029903184  ResponseCount  
ColID      QuestionID RowID                                  
3029903193 316923119  3029903189         803           3142  
3029903194 316923119  3029903189         773           3120  

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

Finally, you have a `MenuID` column. I've left it out of my answer since you don't specify how it's calculated and if it's unique to each group. You'll probably want something like `df.groupby(['ColID', 'QuestionID', 'RowID'])['MenuID']` and `.sum()` or `.head(1)` on that.

Comment: This almost worked how I need it, so the I need it to be represented so that I can access it like the secondary dictionary so if I did counts[0]['3029903181']  I'd get 773

Comment: Oops forgot about that part. Glad you figured it out.